# How to execute a script at the end of and Magento Order process?

Tags: magento, zend-framework, mage

I'm building my very own checkout method in Magento atm. I've created a PHP script with the functionality to redirect the user after filling in the order details to my custom payment page. The script on itself is working but it is fired to early in the order process. When enabled, the user is imidiately redirected when he or she clicks on the "go to checkout button" without filling in the order details. So my PHP script is seen by Magento and the method is fired right away (I'm using the _contruct method).

So now it's the following procedure:
User select product -> User goes to shopping basket -> User clicks on checkout -> user gets redirected.

I want it to be as follows:
User select product -> User goes to shopping basket -> User clicks on checkout -> user fills in order details and selects my shipping method if prefered -> User clicks on "finish order and make payment" -> User gets redirected cuz now the script is executed.

I use the following syntax for my PHP script:

```
 public function __construct()
{ my PHP code here with the redirect };
```

How do I get the PHP script to be executed when the user is done with selecting shipping adres, billing adres and have selected my payment method..?

Comment: Maybe try to read a book/basics about magento before actually trying to code anything ? Hint: use events

Comment: @Bixi thx for the tip. I'm working with a team of coding students. We have experience in programming but not with the Magento framework. We will look into the Magento events, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event/observer method of magento to do something after order is placed.

you can use this event `sales_order_place_after`

Just create one module to listen magento observer/event.

In your /app/code/local/{namespace}/{yourmodule}/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
        ...
        <frontend>
            ...
            <events>
                <sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                        <unique_event_name>
                            <class>{{modulename}}/observer</class>
                            <method>your function name</method>
                        </unique_event_name>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_place_after>
            </events>
            ...
        </frontend>
        ...
    </config>
```

And then create an Observer class at /app/code/local/{namespace}/{yourmodule}/Model/Observer.php

```
    class <namespace>_<modulename>_Model_Observer
   {
      public function your function name(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
      {
          whatever your logic put here
      }

   }
```